# Windows 10: Does the recovery partition need to be mounted all the time?

Tags: windows-10

I plan on adding a few partitions to my disk - at least two - and I'm wondering if I need my recovery partition to be mounted constantly. I'm not looking to delete it (which is what google assumed I wanted to do), I'm just wondering if it can be unmounted most of the time so that I can use its drive letter for something else. I know I could just assign it to Z:\, but it also shows up in other places (like file explorer), and since I don't need it most of the time it seems better to just unmount it.

I also have a smaller "RE tools" partition which isn't mounted at all; I assume this contains repair tools as opposed to full restore functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not need to be mounted.

You can safely remove the drive letter from it and all will be fine.